# Regex to fix decimal value

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a decimal value regex. I have created regex for matching decimal value:

`^-?\d*([\.,]\d*)?$`

This checks for all requirements about decimal ( negative/positive values, only one `-` char on the beginning, only one `.` char etc.

Right now I'm trying to create regex for fixing wrong specified decimal value

My first option was to create **replace** regex like
`[^.0-9-,]` This removes all chars that should not exist in decimal, but it allows to enter for example value:
-12.12.12.12.12
which of course is wrong.

Can you please help me with **replace** regex which will 'fix' my decimal value (remove all unnecessary characters)

----EDIT----

Examples of inputs and results:

-12.12 -> -12.12      [No changes]

-12.12.12 -> -12.1212 [Removed wrong . char]

--12 -> -12           [Removed all - signs that are inside value]

128-22 -> 12822       [Same as before]

12- -> 12             [Remove - at last position]

-12. -> -12.          [leave last . char (if it's first in a value)]

Comment: Be careful, `-`, `-.` and `-,` are valid matches for that regex

Comment: You're tackling this problem the wrong way round  :( You should simply reject invalid input instead of trying to make assumptions as to which points or commas are now thousand separators or decimal separators or whatever...

Comment: Have you got some examples of decimals that you are trying to fix? and what you want them fixing to?

Comment: Can you give some input examples which you try to fix along with the expected output for each?

Comment: Also: What is the bigger picture? Do you need to "fix" large old textfiles?

Comment: Added examples. About 'bigger picture' : I need to validate each char entered to a textBox and fix it while entered. It will be just 1 number per string.

Comment: @Tomasz, if this is just about validating users input into a textbox then you are going about it in the wrong way, [How to create a numeric textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms229644%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: If you're validating user input, just tell the users that the input is wrong and why.  You're not going to be able to account for every kind of incorrect input that a random user will provide.  Users find new, strange and unusual ways of inputting data every day.

Comment: Also, `-1.0e-6` would be a valid decimal number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
string pattern = @"^-?((?<bad>[^\d\.,])|\d)*([\.,](\d|(?<bad>\D+))*)?$";
bool done = false;
while (!done) {
    var bad = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups["bad"];

    if (bad.Success) {
        input = input.Remove(bad.Index, bad.Length);
    } else {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

Fixes some of your examples, namely:

- **-12.12.12**
- **--12**
- **128-22**
- **12-**

Your other examples don't change, as requested.
Also fixes for example: **12.12.-1dfd2.1-2**

Be careful though, it is practically impossible to test all possibilities so i might have missed something.

**Recursive option:**

```
    public static string FixDecimal(string input) {
        var bad = Regex.Match(input, @"^-?((?<bad>[^\d\.,])|\d)*([\.,](\d|(?<bad>\D+))*)?$").Groups["bad"];

        if (bad.Success) {
            return FixDecimal(input.Remove(bad.Index, bad.Length));
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }
```